# Cloudflare proxy - always US IP?

Tags: server, proxy, ip, load-balancing, cloudflare

How it's possible that **Cloudflare** proxy has always US IP address or **Google**, **Netflix** and etc when i access on their websites from Asia, why i don't see some Asia IP (I expected the most close server to me and not in US).

Why i connect like first to US IP, ok, they will have some kind of load balancer server, but for the most low latency for **TTFB** why it's works like that or is the US IP address associated to some Asia server?? What is the trick?

I tried find some info how it's works but it's always same answer and doesn't explain anything for me..it's just saying that it's in power of DNS..I know about GEO DNS, but there is my end, but simple GEO DNS will always show different IP then is there another layer of something?

I'm just lost..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the "proxy" feature of Cloudflare will always display and "use" an US based IP-Address.

Your request is still sent to the nearest Cloudflare data center (somewhere in Asia, in your case).

But the "proxy" IP (which is static), is always the same.

Not entirely sure though, might as well be worth contacting their support team and asking for exact information on this.